# Anyone can give an example on how to use shoppy.gg's API to create (store) a product in Python?

Tags: python, api

Anyone can give an example on how to use shoppy.gg's API to create (store) a product in Python ?

Document :
https://docs.shoppy.gg/#store-a-product

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python requests module to send a PUT request as mentioned in the doc.
Here is a sample:

```
import requests
url = 'https://shoppy.gg/api/v1/products/'
APIKEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"

headers = {
    "Authorization": APIKEY,
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}

# Create product using API

params = '{"title": "Test Product", "price": 10, "type": "service","email": {"enabled": false},"currency": "USD"}'

product_create = requests.request('PUT', url=url, data=params, headers=headers)

print(product_create.text)
```

Comment: How could I get all of my shoppy products rendered in a html file?